# Optimize the time taken to find the minimum distance between two lat/long points belonging to two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have two tables having around 40k rows in each. Each storing lat/longs in them and i need to find out lat/long from 'table 2' which is at least distance from lat/long of 'table 1' for each lat/long of 'table 1'.

For the purpose i am using the following queries but it takes a lot of time as my query traverse through whole 40k*40k rows so am possibly looking for some optimization that can be done for the same.

```
    $select_Table1 = 'Select id, latn, longe from table1';
    $table1Data = mysqli_query($connection,$select_Table1) or die("error :".mysqli_error($connecttion));
    $radius = 6371;//Mean radius of earth
    $deg2Rad = (pi()/180);

    while($table1_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($table1Data))
    {
        $table1Id = $table1_rows[0];
        $table1Lat = $table1_rows[1];
        $table1Long = $table1_rows[2];
        $a = "Select $radius * acos(sin($deg2Rad*($table1Lat)) * sin($deg2Rad*(table2.lat)) +  cos($deg2Rad*($table1Lat)) * cos($deg2Rad*(table2.lat)) * cos($deg2Rad*($table1Long-table2.long))) as Distance from table2 order by Distance limit 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $a) or die("Error :".mysqli_error($connection));
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            //Some calculations here
        }
    }
```

Moreover the tables are dynamic, they are frequently changed so pre computation is not possible.

Comment: Look at the extensions for spatial data:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html.

Comment: See joins. Executing queries inside loops is a terrible idea.